# Istio outbound https traffic troubleshooting

Tags: kubernetes, mesh, istio, envoyproxy

I have 2 AKS clusters, Cluster 1 and Cluster 2 both running Istio 1.14 minimal out-of-the-box (default configs).

Everything on Cluster 1 works as expected (after deploying Istio).

On Cluster 2, all HTTPS outbound connections initiated from my services (injected with istio-proxy) fail.

```
curl http://www.google.com  #works
curl https://www.google.com #fails
```

If I create a service entry for google, then the https curl works:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: google
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

Both Istio installations are out-of-the-box so `meshConfig.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode` is set to `ALLOW_ANY` (double-checked).

I read online that there were some Istio bugs that would cause this behavior, but I don't think it's the case here. I also compared the Istio configs between the 2 clusters and they really seem to be the same.

I'm starting to think the problem may lie in some cluster configs because I know there are some differences between the 2 clusters here.

How would you go about troubleshooting this? Do you think the issue is related to Istio or Cluster services/configs? What should I look into first?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  By default ALLOW_ANY is value set for meshConfig.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode. This can be verified in the cluster by running below command.

```
kubectl get configmap istio -n istio-system -o yaml | grep -o "mode: ALLOW_ANY"
```

Please also refer the [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/) for the options available in accessing external services

Comment: kubectl get istiooperator installed-state -n istio-system -o jsonpath='{.spec.meshConfig.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode}'

You should either see ALLOW_ANY or no output (default ALLOW_ANY).